# Laravel form input not returning

Tags: php, input, laravel, laravel-4, return-value

I have a problem with form input not returning. I was following this guide here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aq0EcYEshwM Here is the code:

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', function() { 
    return View::make('test');
});

Route::post('create', array(
    'as' => 'create', //name
    function(){
        //return inputs
        return View::make('create');
    }
));
```

**test.blade.php**

```
<form action="{{URL::route('create')}}" method="post">
    Name <input type="text" name="name" id="" >
    <br>
    Password <input type="password" name="password" id="" >
    <br>
    <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

**create.blade.php**

```
Inputs
<br>
name = {{Input::get('name')}};
<br>
password = {{Input::get('password')}};
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Btw: You don't need the semicolons in create.blade.php

Comment: After inputting data in the form i get: 

Not Found
The requested URL /laravel/public/create was not found on this server.
Edit: removed semicolons - still recieving error message.

Comment: Ok, sounds like your server is misconfigured. What are you using? Have you set up a virtual host and enabled mod_rewrite? Alternatively you can use PHP's built in development server by running `php -S localhost:8000 server.php` from the command line in the **root** directory of your project (**not** public/). Or just run: `php artisan serve --port=8080 --host=local.dev`

Comment: did you run `composer dump-autoload` after changing the `routes.php` file ?

Comment: I did these codes, and this is the result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fl1s4zk3d1163ne/laravel1.png

Very unsure what to do next.
File structure: https://www.dropbox.com/s/95amv6grbkc55ge/firestructure.png 
This is the fault i get: https://www.dropbox.com/s/k5cnblf4sj26xbo/feilmelding.png

Comment: You need to enable mod-rewrite AND make sure that it is "allowed" for whatever folder you are using to serve Laravel, e.g. path/to/your/laravel/public/